# how to delete duplicated duplicated of each column after group_by() using `dplyr` package

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a data.frame `mydata` like this

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  b  a      
2  a  b     c   
3  a  b        d
4  x  y  h      
5  x  y     k  e
```

I want to group it by the columns `V1`and `V2`, and delete the `""` string in the other columns

the result should like this

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  b  a  c  d
2  x  y  h  k  e
```

is their a efficient way to do this using the `dplyr` package? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr/tidyr`.  We reshape the data from 'wide' to 'long' using `gather`, remove the blank elements in the 'Val' column with `filter`, and reshape it back to 'wide' format with `spread`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
gather(mydata, Var, Val, V3:V5) %>% 
              filter(Val!='') %>% 
              spread(Var, Val)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a  b  a  c  d
#2  x  y  h  k  e
```

Or another approach using only `dplyr` (if the number of non-blank values are the same across each groups) would be to group by 'V1', 'V2', and use `summarise_each` to select only the elements that are not blank (`.[.!='']`)

```
 mydata %>%
       group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(.[.!='']))
 #  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 #1  a  b  a  c  d
 #2  x  y  h  k  e
```

---

We can also use `data.table` to do this.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydata)`), grouped by 'V1', 'V2', we loop through the other columns (`lapply(.SD, ...)`) and subset the elements that are not blank.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(mydata)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) x[x!='']) ,.(V1, V2)]
 #   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 #1:  a  b  a  c  d
 #2:  x  y  h  k  e
```

---

Similar approach using `aggregate` from `base R` is

```
 aggregate(.~V1+V2, mydata, FUN=function(x) x[x!=''])
 #  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 #1  a  b  a  c  d
 #2  x  y  h  k  e
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "x", "x"),
V2 = c("b", "b", 
"b", "y", "y"), V3 = c("a", "", "", "h", ""), V4 = c("", "c", 
"", "", "k"), V5 = c("", "", "d", "", "e")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: @ZihuGuo Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Using base R, if that's of interest

```
x <- data.frame(V1 = c(rep("a", 3), "x", "x"), 
    V2 = c(rep("b", 3), "y", "y"), 
    V3= c("a", "", "", "h", ""), 
    V4 = c("", "c", "", "", "k"), 
    V5 = c(rep("", 2), "d", "", "e"))

temp <- lapply(x[], function(y) as.character(unique(y[y != ""])))
data.frame(do.call(cbind,temp))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  b  a  c  d
2  x  y  h  k  e
```

Comment: a couple `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` parameters might be handy to include as well.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Can you please elaborate?  I'm not sure I completely follow